# How do i display a page/component once In React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I just got my first job as a react developer and I was asked to create a one time page for users to answer some questions (like a form) and after the users have answered all the questions and submitted the question page shouldn't come up again.

I have created the page for the questions. But I have no idea on how to display the page only once

Can someone please help me out. I'll really appreciate.. Thanks

Comment: You should ask your mentor at work. We would need to know your codebase to know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a backend for storing the user data, and a field in the database that will be equal to 0 or 1, if the user doesn't answer the question will be equal to 0 if he answers will be equal to 1.

Comment: I was thinking of storing it in local Storage for now just to test it and after it's successful I'll store the data in the BACKEND. Can you please tell me more about the field you talked about above?

Comment: Let's call the field `question`, when the user enters your website, check in your local store, if this field `question` exists or not, if it doesn't exist, then show the questions page, after finishing the questions set the `question` field in you localStorage = 1,

Comment: If the user enters the website and you checked the field and it exists, just doesn't show the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch between pages (like, whole pages, url and all), you may find useful to check the library **React-router**. react-router is a library that helps you switch between different pages, and you can put any logic you want in it, for selecting the pages you want to display.

You probably will need to save and retrieve your state to find out when to show the correct page. And for that, one way could be using Redux, and storing your global state in localStorage. I'll leave the docs for Redux too below. Hope this helps!

resources:

- [react-router docs](https://reactrouter.com/)
- [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/)